# Inject TestRestTemplate for RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a component which is auto wiring RestTemplate. I want to use that component for testing, but want to use TestRestTemplate. As I can see, TestRestTRemplate and RestTemplate is not connected through any interface.

RestTemplate implements RestOperations but TestRestTemplate doesn't. Is there elegant way to inject TestRestTemplate in RestTemplate, or some other alternate to achieve it?

I have created my own version of RestTemplate to use it in test and prod

```
@Autowired
private MyRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

---

```
public class MyRestTemplate {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new TestRestTemplate().getRestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you able to show your code

Comment: added my code which I am trying to make it working. But I want to use testresttemplate rather than resttemplate

Comment: `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "Test")
  public class CustomTest {  @Autowired
private MyRestTemplate restTemplate;  @Test
 public void test() { //your custom testing }}`

Comment: use like above you can directly auto wire your RestTemplate in Testing

Comment: This is same as SpringRunner and can only  auto wire rest template, not testresttemplate.

Comment: TestRestTemplate is intended for use in your tests, not in components that you are testing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have created MyRestTemplate utility, which is using rest template to call other services, but is also doing Validator.validate before calling, to validate the request. On the top, it checks for the response status and other response validation too. This is working fine in prod, but I am not able to replace rest template with testresttemplate in my integration test, so that MyRestTemplate usages test rest template rather than rest template.